# Using those characters only/with out adding, replacing, or removing is my sentence structure and grammar correct?

Tags: grammar, mandarin, simplified-characters, sentence-structure, word-order

Can someone please help me? I suck at forming sentences in Chinese. I know if I practice I would get better but I have no one to check if my sentence structure is correct. Hopefully, it is!
一）我请你和我想一起听音乐。
二）我和我的好朋友昨天晚上去图书馆看书。
三）哪里哪里，我写字写得很慢。
四）我的妈妈常常说别看电影。
五）白安觉得他来念书念得不错。
六）他没听录音可是有课文预习。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一）我请你和我想一起听音乐。 incorrect - (*it is either 请你和我一起听音乐 or 我想和你一起听音乐,* )

二）我和我的好朋友昨天晚上去图书馆看书。 correct

三）哪里哪里，我写字写得很慢。 correct

四）我的妈妈常常说别看电影。 correct

五）白安觉得他来念书念得不错。 incorrect - (*it should be "白安觉得他念书念得不错"*

*'他**来**'念书' implies a '**suggestion**' ; '念书念得不错' is a '**statement**', the two don't mix )*

六）他没听录音可是有课文预习。incorrect - (*it should be 他没听录音可是有预习课文, [没听] is a **verb**, if it is followed by "可是有 **but have**" then the following must be another **verb** [预习], not a **noun** [课文预习]*)

Answer (score 0):

第一句话）我请你和我想一起听音乐。
    我请你和我一起听音乐。

第二句话）我和我的好朋友昨天晚上去图书馆看书。
    我和我的好朋友昨天晚上去图书馆看书。

第三句话）哪里哪里，我写字写得很慢。
    哪里哪里，我写字写得很慢。

第四句话）我的妈妈常常说别看电影。
    我的妈妈常常说别看电影。

第五句话）白安觉得他来念书念得不错。
    白安觉得他来念书念得不错。

第六句话）他没听录音可是有课文预习。
    Not sure what you want to say exactly (your class perspective is student or teacher??), maybe:

'I'm not listening to music because I've got an essay to write.'
我没有时间听音乐，因为我有一篇文章要写。

or

'I'm not listening to music because I've got to learn a text by heart.'
我没有时间听音乐，因为我必须背诵一篇课文。